# How is convolution performed in frequency domain?

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform

I know the method and formula for convolution in time domain. And according to properties of FT, convolution in time domain in multiplication in frequency domain and vice versa.
I want to know how convolution is performed in frequency domain?(the math stuff)

Comment: well the same way $\hat{f} \ast \hat{g}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\xi-u) \hat{g}(u)du$, this symmetry between time domain and frequency domain is because the Fourier transform is really the same as the inverse Fourier transform (equivalently the Fourier transform is an unitary linear operator)

Comment: and showing that $\mathcal{F}[f g](\xi) = \hat{f} \ast \hat{g}(\xi) $ is straightforward. The converse $\mathcal{F}[f  \ast g](\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi) \hat{g}(\xi) $ is more complicated and requires the Fourier inversion theorem $\mathcal{F}^{-1} = \mathcal{F}^*$ so that $f  \ast g (x) =  \mathcal{F}^*[\hat{f} \hat{g}](x) \implies \mathcal{F}[f  \ast g](\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi) \hat{g}(\xi) $